# Rails 4 fomatting with slim error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, slim-lang

i have this simple erb code that works perfectly, joint to my `i18n.yml` file. The idea is to get the client's `edit.html.erb` page, get the title of that page in my `en.yml` file and pass that title the `@client.fullname` variable. Like so:

```
<h1><%= t('client.edit.title'), :current_client => @client.fullname %></h1>
```

Now, i'm in the process of translating my erb files into slim. So the result of that line of code is

```
h1 = t('client.edit.title'), :current_client => @client.fullname
```

But it wouldnt pass the variable to the `en.yml` file. Instead, it throws this error:

```
/app/views/clients/edit.html.slim:1: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')' ...tty2 = (t('client.edit.title'), :current_client => @client.f... ... ^
```

Would anyone know what i'm doing wrong here?

Comment: The only way i could make it relative work was passing the :current_client option with the translation identifier string: = t('client.edit.title', :current_client => @client.fullname)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hash parameter options should be passed within the method call parentheses, like so

```
h1 = t('client.edit.title', :current_client => @client.fullname)
```

Not sure why this would have worked in ERB, but it doesn't look correct as written.

You can also remove the parentheses altogether

```
h1 = t 'client.edit.title', :current_client => @client.fullname
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
h1
  = t('client.edit.title'), :current_client => @client.fullname
```